# How to limit whole paginate not limit page

Tags: cakephp, pagination, limit

The code is Ok,
but how to limit whole query
i want to show only 500 record of 3 000 total by 25 per page
so finally 20 pages will shown not 120

`$this->Question->recursive = 1;

$this->paginate = array(

    'limit' => 25,

    'order' => array('Question.views' => 'DESC')

);

    $this->set('questions', $this->paginate('Question'));

    $listing_header = 'Популярные вопросы';

    $this->set(compact('listing_header'));

    $this->render('/questions/listing');`

Answer (score 0):

http://tycamtech.com/php/cakephp/51-basics/126-limit-pagination-results-per-page-and-total-number-of-results

How does that solve the problem? Seems like a simple problem with a potentially simple solution!

Best of luck!